# Computer science: Concatenate two lists recursive definition

Tags: computer-science, recursion

concatenate two lists recursive definition.

This is the exercise:

$concatenate(L1, L2)$ , returns concatenation of $L1$ with $L2$.

I guessed the Base Case is:

$concatenate ([],[])$ $[]$ being empty lists, the concatenation is $[]$.

Now, I don't know how do I get the recursive Case, can you please help me ?

Comment: It's a nice question, recursion can be tough, but try asking this in https://stackoverflow.com/ instead! Good luck!

Comment: Yep, could be, but this is math, I don't want to go technical with the question, so I decided to ask here @rhkoulen, is it wrong?

Comment: I suppose not, I'll give it a go, but I'm afraid a moderator will close it while I'm typing.

Comment: I don't understand why you would even need recursion if you're not trying to preserve order in the final result. Are you trying to?

Comment: I don't know either it's just an subject exercise

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: I'm struggling with the recursive case I don't know what to propose, I just thought that if the lists longitude are greater than 1 then go to the end of the $L1$ list and then concatenate the final element with the $L2$'s first element. @HallaSurvivor

Comment: @RuStiKiDeaS So you're using normal concatenation to define a recursive concatenation?

Comment: Then, concatenate(L1, L2, product) =  product if L1 != [] and L2 != [] :: concatenate([], L2, product + L1) if L1 != []  :: concatenate(L1, [], product + L1) if L1 = [] and L2 != []. I'll reiterate, there's no point to defining a recursive concatenation.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021894/how-to-define-a-recursive-function-to-merge-two-sorted-lists-and-return-a-new-li) provides a good example of a case when you'd want to use recursion: conserving order (note, it's on stack overflow).

Comment: I have already implemented a merge recursive algorithm, but I just don't see why do a recursive algorithm to concatenate two lists. :(

Comment: @RuStiKiDeaS:  As Readers we have to rely on you, the Original Poster, to know why you are asking.  Your choppy wording even creates doubt about what you are asking. Instead of the phrase "concatenate two lists recursive definition" you should write a complete sentence, like "How does one recursively define the concatenation of two lists?"  This is very natural exercise in a language like Prolog or Lisp.  But the little context you give is somewhat inconsistent about your motivation/application.  Concatenation is not "merging" two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tackle this problem, you need a way to convey information throughout recursive calls. The way I would do this is probably overloading, but that's a little computer science-y so I'll skip that.

Our function would be $concatenate(L_1,L_2,L)$ =

$$\hspace{4.75cm}L \text{ if } L_1 =[] \text{ and } L_2 =[]$$
$$concatenate([],L_2,L+L_1) \text{ if } L_1 \neq[] \text{ and } L_2 =[]$$
$$concatenate(L_1,[],L+L_2) \text{ if } L_1=[] \text{ and } L_2\neq[]$$
$$concatenate([],L_2,L+L_1) \text{ if } L_1\neq[] \text{ and } L_2\neq[]$$

This formula is the same as $concatenate(L_1,L_2,L)=concatenate([],[],L_1+L_2) = L_1+L_2$

If you already have a defined concatenation, there's literally no use for recursion, as you're gaining no new functionality, just wasting stack memory. The only thing recursion does here is handle edge cases that don't even raise issue.

Even in the situation you describe in the comments, where you add one element at a time to the beginning of $L_2$ until $L_1$ is empty, can be achieved by looping the same instruction until $L_1$ is empty.

Sorry if I sound rude, but there's no reason to define concatenation recursively.

Comment: Thanks! you weren't rude it's the truth, there is no reason to define concatenation recursively hahaha, but this problem is from a book haha